# Sequelize many-to-many updating junction table

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I don't see how i can update an junction table with multiple id's. So i want to update a junction table so that those rows with ids that are missing leave, and new ones are created.

This is my setup

```
  ActorFilm.belongsTo(models.Actor, { foreignKey: 'actorId', targetKey: 'id' });
  ActorFilm.belongsTo(models.Film, { foreignKey: 'filmId', targetKey: 'id' });

  Actor.belongsToMany(models.Film, { through: models.ActorFilm, foreignKey: 'actorId' });

  Film.belongsToMany(models.Actor, { through: models.ActorFilm, foreignKey: 'filmId' });
```

This is how i am add new Actor:

```
    const actor= await Actor.create({
        userId: userId,
        title: title,
        description: description
    });

    if (filmIds && filmIds.length) {
        await actor.setFilms(filmIds );
        const actorWithFilms = Actor.findByPk(actor.id, { include: Film });
        return actorWithFilms ;
    }
    
    return actor;
```

And i want to update Actorlike that:

```
   const editedActor = await Actor.update({
        title: title,
        description: description,
    }, {
        where: {
            id: actorId
        },
        returning: true,
    });

    return editedActor;
```

Where i need to put new ids array so that those that are missing leave, and new ones are created in junction table. Or should I first delete the unnecessary ones myself, check those that already exist and add new ones?

Comment: Isn't the call `await actor.setFilms(filmIds );` enough to delete old film links and add new ones?

Comment: @Anatoly Strange but initially it didn't work for me, now I decided to try it again and everything is working fine, thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```js
await actor.setFilms(filmIds );
```

it deletes old link records and added new ones.